# Does IE11 support window.moveTo(x,y)?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

The problem is self explanatory.

The context is as follows, I'm trying to open three windows using window.open(), on my three monitors. It does not accept negative values, and for that I need an alternative way to locate each window to a screen. I would like this to work on IE11.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/moveTo hasnt been of great help.

Edit:
window.moveTo works on windows opened using the window.open() method, but they only move the opened window within the screen( 0,0 to 1920*1024 in my case)

Comment: https://www.caniuse.com/#search=moveTo says 'Unknown' for IE11... and that could mean 'No'

Comment: Jsfiddle, codepen... Try it

Comment: i have. it didnt work. but this question isnt out there on the internet, not that i could find it. so i wrote it in such a manner as to help others while also getting a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to refer this explanation given by Mike Burr may help to understand the logic behind it.

> Depending on how your video driver handles multiple monitors (as 2 
>   logical screens or 1 logical screen), this will cause the moveto(0,0) 
>   method to place the window on whatever logical screen the window is
>   on.  In my experience, most video drivers manipulate multiple monitors
>   as  separate logical screens (typically leaving the Windows task bar
>   across  the left monitor), thus leading to the behavior that you
>   described. I  have seen some Nvidia cards and drivers that stretch the
>   taskbar across  both monitors (and would possibly allow the
>   moveto(0,0) to move the  window to the left monitor because both
>   screens are being manipulated as  a single logical screen). Hope this
>   helps.

Reference:

[javascript moveTo(0,0): strange behavior in multiple monitor environment](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/05ce069b-2fe2-4364-bb40-483521d8ef40/javascript-moveto00-strange-behavior-in-multiple-monitor-environment?forum=jscript)

Comment: Funny thing is that moveTo(0,0) moves my window to (0,0) on the monitor it was opened in. while if i run IE11 through VS2015 Community edition, moveTo(0,0) moves the window to (0,0) on the main monitor.

Comment: Looks like Visual studio opening the IE on main window give that result.